# CLR assemblies can bring a security flaw to the SQL Server instance

Tags: sql, sql-server, security

I have run the SSMS Vulnerability Assessment.

In the result it give **4** total Failing checks.

In the 4 failing 1 is CLR assembly.

VA1256 - User CLR assemblies should not be defined in the database

**how to slove this problem?**

Using  CLR Assemblies are safe or not.
If it not safe.  **What is the alternative for CLR.**

**Give below the detail of result:**

```
 "VA1256": {
          "RuleId": "VA1256",
          "Severity": "High",
          "Category": "SurfaceAreaReduction",
          "RuleType": "NegativeList",
          "Title": "User CLR assemblies should not be defined in the database",
          "Description": "CLR assemblies can be used to execute arbitrary code on SQL Server process. This rule checks that there are no user-defined CLR assemblies in the database",
          "Rationale": "Using CLR assemblies can bring a security flaw to the SQL Server instance and to all other network resources accessible from it",
          "IsFirstPartyRule": false,
          "MitigatedBy": "VA1023",

        }
```

I have used **"WITH PERMISSION_SET = SAFE"** in Create Assembly.

Answer (score 0):

Your choices are either to not use CLR at all and disable the option or ignore the recommendation. We can't suggest alternatives unless you add details of the functionality you are using to your question.

Assuming you have a good reason to use CLR in the first place, you can mitigate security risks with proper controls, allowing:

- only SAFE assemblies
- only privileged users (e.g. sysadmin role members) to create CLR assemblies
- assemblies only from trusted sources (e.g. built from your reviewed source code)

Comment: Hi Dan Guzman, I am using CLR for Searching values from  Entire Database all  column in the table with some condition.

Comment: @krisurnok, cannot that search functionality be performed using T-SQL?

Comment: Yes ,We can but little slow compare to CLR

Comment: we have it in T-SQL first then only moved to CLR by senior suggestion

Comment: To solve the "problem", revert to the T-SQL solution. Be aware that despite the verbiage in the security assessment, your organization is free to use whatever features you deem necessary and accept/mitigate risks accordingly. The purpose of the assessment is to make sure you are aware of the associated risks, which is not to say the features should not be used. Otherwise, Microsoft would remove the feature from the product entirely.